# How to write dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have to append dataframe to csv file. I tried doing it this way:

```
with open('datewiseTrainingdata.csv', mode='a') as f:
    sheet1.to_csv(f, header=False)
```

This adds blank lines in between rows. I tried doing it this way:

```
with open('datewiseTrainingdata.csv', mode='wb') as f:
    sheet1.to_csv(f, header=False)
```

But it overwrites. How should I approach this problem?
Edit:
tried using newline as well it gives the following error

TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: See the description of the first option here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html --- note the should be opened with `newline=''` bit --- not sure if this solves your problem or not, but try it out!

Comment: Also, note that you don't have to pass a file object. You can pass just the filename directly and pandas will open it. `to_csv` has a `mode` keyword as well---presumably pandas will know how to append it properly.

Comment: @alkasm tried that first, it gives an error (
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
)

Comment: What gives an error? What's the full traceback? Please add that into the question.

Comment: `newline` is a keyword argument for `open()`, not for `to_csv()`.